# How to enable OpenID Connect in Dataverse

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, openid, dataverse

I have developed an OpenID Connect Provider and now want to configure Dataverse's login approach so that users can authenticate themselves through my OpenID Connect Provider.

I have set the following options in Dataverse (i.e., `/usr/local/payara6/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`):

```
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.enabled=true</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.client-id=some_id</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.client-secret=some_secret</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.auth-server-url=https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.title=OpenID Title</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.subtitle=OpenID SubTitle</jvm-options>
```

I restarted the service using command `/usr/local/payara6/bin/asadmin restart-domain domain1`.

Now I expect to see a new button (for OpenID Connect) in the Dataverse's login view but I do not see such a thing and only the normal login button is - as always - shown. Also I see the logs using the command `cat /usr/local/payara6/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log` and the logs show the following:

> [2024-03-07T10:59:39.449+0000] [Payara 6.2023.8] [SEVERE] [] [edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.AuthenticationProvidersRegistrationServiceBean] [tid: _ThreadID=70 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1709809179449] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> Exception setting up an OIDC auth provider via MicroProfile Config
> edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.exceptions.AuthorizationSetupException: OIDC provider metadata at https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration/ not parsable.
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.providers.oauth2.oidc.OIDCAuthProvider.getMetadata(OIDCAuthProvider.java:129)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.providers.oauth2.oidc.OIDCAuthProvider.(OIDCAuthProvider.java:91)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.providers.oauth2.oidc.OIDCAuthenticationProviderFactory.buildFromSettings(OIDCAuthenticationProviderFactory.java:67)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.AuthenticationProvidersRegistrationServiceBean.startup(AuthenticationProvidersRegistrationServiceBean.java:129)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1022)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:204)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor226.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:978)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:204)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor224.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:978)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:418)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:381)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2071)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:585)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:743)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:477)
> at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
> at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer._getContext(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:189)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:85)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2607)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2024)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
> at jdk.proxy76/jdk.proxy76.$Proxy344.getAuthenticationProvidersMap(Unknown Source)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.**EJB31_Generated__AuthenticationProvidersRegistrationServiceBean__Intf____Bean**.getAuthenticationProvidersMap(Unknown Source)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.AuthenticationServiceBean.getAuthenticationProviderIdsOfType(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:150)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:588)
> at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:408)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4835)
> at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:653)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:834)
> at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:603)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor289.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
> at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:603)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor224.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4807)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4795)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
> at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
> at jdk.proxy76/jdk.proxy76.$Proxy394.getAuthenticationProviderIdsOfType(Unknown Source)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.authorization.**EJB31_Generated__AuthenticationServiceBean__Intf____Bean**.getAuthenticationProviderIdsOfType(Unknown Source)
> at edu.harvard.iq.dataverse.LoginPage.init(LoginPage.java:111)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.glassfish.expressly.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:186)
> at org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
> at org.glassfish.expressly.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:248)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
> at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
> at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:70)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:62)
> at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:506)
> at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:858)
> at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:56)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
> at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
> at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
> at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:83)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
> at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
> at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
> ]]

Also, the following is the output of the `https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration`:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://my.oidc.com/api/auth",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/oauth-access-token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/oauth-user-profile",
  "jwks_uri": "https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/.well-known/jwks.json",
  "response_types_supported": ["code", "token", "id_token", "code id_token"],
  "subject_types_supported": ["public", "pairwise"],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256", "ES256", "HS256"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.auth-server-url=https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration

I should have used:

-Ddataverse.auth.oidc.auth-server-url=https://my.oidc.com/api/auth/